# What does string.unpack('<I2s2', data) mean in Lua script?

Tags: python, lua, nmap

I debugging a line in `nmap` script and got this:

```
local target_info = '\x02\x00\x1a\x00W\x00I\x00N\x00S\x00E\x00R\x00V\x00E\x00R\x002\x000\x001\x002\x00\x01\x00\x1e\x00W\x00I\x00N\x00-\x00V\x00B\x00N\x00G\x00O\x007\x00T\x00N\x008\x00N\x00S\x00\x04\x00&\x00w\x00i\x00n\x00s\x00e\x00r\x00v\x00e\x00r\x002\x000\x001\x002\x00.\x00l\x00o\x00c\x00a\x00l\x00\x03\x00F\x00W\x00I\x00N\x00-\x00V\x00B\x00N\x00G\x00O\x007\x00T\x00N\x008\x00N\x00S\x00.\x00w\x00i\x00n\x00s\x00e\x00r\x00v\x00e\x00r\x002\x000\x001\x002\x00.\x00l\x00o\x00c\x00a\x00l\x00\x05\x00&\x00w\x00i\x00n\x00s\x00e\x00r\x00v\x00e\x00r\x002\x000\x001\x002\x00.\x00l\x00o\x00c\x00a\x00l\x00\x07\x00\x08\x00\xca\xa5\xb7\xbfq\xbd\xd6\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00'

av_id, value, pos = string.unpack( "<I2s2", target_info, 0 )
print(av_id, value, pos)
```

Result in

```
2   WINSERVER2012   31
```

According to the docs: `s[n]: a string preceded by its length coded as an unsigned integer with n bytes (default is a size_t)` (https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.2)

But I'm not sure what does unpack format `s2` means and when it stop? The `target_info` have more information behind and I really want to convert this to Python code.

Answer (score 6):

`s2` means that the first two bytes give the length of the string.
These two bytes are `\x1a\x00` and so the length is 26.
This is consistent with the 31 printed for pos: 2+2+26=30.
The string appears to be `WINSERVER2012` and have length 13 but there are NUL bytes after each letter.